# Aggregate data with one query using entity framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-extended

We use EF 6 without Stored Procedures.

Doing a reporting chart showing aggregated data from a start-/enddate:

Every aggregation of that data must use this datetime filter:

```
Number of customer 100 (100%)

Number qualified customers 923 (92,3%)

Number accepted  customers 600 (60 %) 
-------------------------------------

(with Order)  60 (10%)
(without  Order)  120 (20%)
(still pending/open) 420 (70%)
```

Is it possible to do the data aggregation with one query? Or maybe multiple queries and execute them at the end? Or will this get too complicated? and I should break down the data fetching in multiple repository calls and do the math stuff in a service?

I would be glad if someone has a good advise for me here.

**UPDATE**:

Finally I found EF extended with the future queries where I can batch up queries.

What I need to return are 6 counts for 6 different where queries.

But Looking at the minimal EF extend future query samples, I do not see a way that I can get that 6 count values with ONE query.

Anyone knows?

Comment: It's difficult to say without knowing more about your entity schema and perhaps a little more info about your database schema as well.

Comment: I updated my question in direction futures queries with EF extended.

Comment: Your classes might help, how do you get a qualified/accepted customer? assuming that with order = `customer.Orders.Any()` how do you tell pending /open. (Also is that supposed to be number of customers `1000` not `100`!

Comment: Can not put classes here. But all info you need is above! again:"What I need to return are 6 counts for 6 different where queries." WHERE queries :-)

Comment: Thanks for the update, but it's very difficult to comment without more specifics. I understand that your code my be sensitive or perhaps very big, but can you create an example. There's some good tips on good question structures here http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve which will encourage people to help.